# ChromeDriver setSystem property issue

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

when I'm trying to run test I have issue as on screenshot, where am I wrong?
thx  [image: click here to see screenshot]

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\Downloads\aaaaaa\src\main\resources\target\test-classes;C:\Users\vol.7\Downloads\aaaaaa\target\classes;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.44.0\selenium-chrome-driver-2.44.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.44.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.44.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.3\gson-2.3.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.44.0\selenium-api-2.44.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.4\httpclient-4.3.4.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.9.9\testng-6.9.9.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.0\ant-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.0\ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.15\snakeyaml-1.15.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\beanshell\bsh\2.0b4\bsh-2.0b4.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.44.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.44.0.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\vol.7\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.1\commons-exec-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0\plugins\testng\lib\testng.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -port 54806 -usedefaultlisteners false -socket54807 -temp C:\Users\vol.7\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng36.tmp
```

> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class Aaas    at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
>     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:166)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:143)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:272)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:114)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)    at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
>     ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to
>   the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property; for more information,    at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:117)
>     at Aaas.(Aaas.java:11)    ... 32 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: error says path to chrome driver cannot be located. update correct path and rerun the test

Comment: but its correct path, u can see chromedriver location in project tree and check

Comment: I think you might have got your problem solve so please make correct answer tick. So efforts get rewards.

Answer (score 1):

In your code it looks like you did 2 mistakes.
First thing...
Please remove the instantiation of "new ChromeDriver()" when a reference of type WebDriver created in class.
Instead create a referece:

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

Then instantiate the chrome driver inside the test case-->

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
    //Here, Before the instantiation just use setProperty method
    System.setProperty("key","path to chrome driver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
}
```

and the Second thing is...

make sure the relative path is correct to chromedriver.exe file...
Use absolute path to the chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not given complete chromediver.exe path. More over over calling chrome driver before system.set property. please set system property first then call chrome driver..

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium_setups\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: with path " "C:\\Users\\vol.7\\Downloads\\aaaaaa\\src\\chromedriver.exe")" doesn't work too

Comment: same exception? can you paste the complete exception instead of image

Comment: you are calling chrome driver before system.setproperty as per your image.. did tried same like answer i provided?

Comment: here is a limit for chars in message, message with exception is to long, so here is image again))
[link](http://snag.gy/6KV9R.jpg)

Comment: did you used system.set property before chrome driver? please place "WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();" after system.set property in that @Test method

Comment: yea, I tried to initiate sys property first but result the same

`public class Aaas {


    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\vol.7\\Downloads\\aaaaaa\\src\\chromedriver.exe");

    }

    @Test
    public void aaa() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");

    }
}`

Comment: can you try one more like this 
  public class Aaas {    
   @Test 
   public void aaa() { 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\vol.7\\Downloads\\aaaaaa\\src\\chromedriver.exe"); 
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
   driver.get("google.com"); 
    
   } 
  }

Comment: the same))) maybe check other driver version?

Comment: good idea.. try with new chrome driver and with new selenium jar just came out yesterday..

Comment: Rather than using 'System.setProperty' why don't you add your driver executable's path to your environment variable Path? that way you don't have to deal with System.setProperty() method and You can be sure that issue is elsewhere and not in setting system path

Comment: good idea...but, just added and the same...don't know what to thing even)

Comment: where is google chrome installed.. for me C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: thanks to all, 
I prove to myself that the best fixing tool is restarting ide/windows/....

after restarting idea everything works fine without any changes....damn it)))

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the new `ChromeDriver` in your (implicit) constructor **before** you're calling: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ...)`

You need to set the property before creating any Drivers (same applies to IE, Opera, etc.)

One approach is to create a `static { ... }` block and move your setting of System properties there. That'll get called before you create your Driver.

Comment: Tried with static at the beggining
like this 
`
static {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\vol.7\\Downloads\\aaaaaa\\src\\chromedriver.exe");
}
    @Test
    public void aaa() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");

    }
}`

Comment: Could you add the complete stacktrace to your post?

Comment: added to post, please check

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a location for the chromedriver binary.  Edit the configuration of your test by clicking on the drop down box in the top bar.  Then add to your VM options a path for the chromedriver binary:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO>/chromedriver
```

Since you are using a maven project you may find this maven plugin useful:

https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin

It will download the driver binaries for you and set up the correct system properties when running your tests through maven.  There is a template that uses it here that you can use as an example of how to get it configured:

https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

****Note**** Running the test through intelliJ is not the same as running it through maven.  System properties that are only set through maven will not have been set in IntelliJ when you run a test through the IDE.  This is why you need to edit your test configuration if you have already set the correct System Properties through maven.